# jQuery Toggle Class on "a" Link Hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, webflow

I have a custom cursor div which changes when hovering over various elements. So far, I have the cursor expanding on hover of `.nav-item-wrapper` and shrinking on hover of `p`.

I'm attempting to have the `.cursor-div is--link` class toggle on hover of all `a` but running into problems.

[The current draft URL](https://portfolio-de-j-bilhan.webflow.io/xxxx)

Here is my jQuery inside of the `<body>`:

```
<script>

$('.nav-item-wrapper').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('is--active');
  $(this).find('.nav-highlight').toggleClass('is--active');
});

/**pointer link hover toggle**/
$('.nav-item-wrapper').not('.w--current').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $('.cursor-div').toggleClass('is--link');
});

/** pointer text hover toggle **/
$('p').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $('.cursor-div').toggleClass('is--text');
});

</script>
```

I attempted to add this but it interferes with the `.nav-item-wrapper` class change.

```
$('a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(cursor-div).toggleClass('is--link');;
});
```

Comment: Please show your html too - see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: @Pete Would a [Read-Only](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/portfolio-de-j-bilhan?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=portfolio-de-j-bilhan&preview=6fad4f2997095102c7e9f77b301d0548&pageId=61eebf0d47226725f7e8b23a&workflow=preview) link into webflow work? I don't know how to create a reprex with the webflow code export

Comment: The question needs enough code in it to see what the problem is without having to go to an external link (otherwise it is off topic for SO) - as your problem seems to be with js html and css, you should be able to create a runnable demo using the snippet button in the wysiwyg if you edit the question

Comment: @Pete Having a difficult time setting up a working sample. 

To simplify, how can I reference all `a` links using jQuery? I know how to set up the toggle. If this is a case-by-case problem than I understand if it's not possible to solve here.